# How can I access variables declared in __init__ of my class in one of it's functions

Tags: python, class, variables, scope, self

```
class Canvas:

  def __init__(self, size: list, void):

    self.size = size
    self.void = void

    self.canvas = []
    self.camera_pos = [0, 0]
    self.sprite_priority = []
    self.sprite = []
    self.distance_from = {}
    self.distances = []


   

    class Sprite:

      def __init__(self, char, position, z_index):

        self.char = char
        self.position = position
        self.z_index = z_index

        self.sprite.append(self)
       

      


  

  def create_canvas(void):
     
     #do code here
     #example:
     get_var = self.size #I want to get size from __init__ but self isn't recognized
```

So I want to get variables in any of my functions that belongs to the Canvas class
but for some reason it doesn't regnonise any of those.

I thought that by putting self at the beginning it would get it but it didn't
so I tried indenting it in an other way but didn't work either.

Comment: `void` isn’t a thing in Python.  Make the parameter to your class method `self` and then you can access the instance attributes via that `self` object.

Comment: @Samwise so do I need to do that :
```
def create_canvas(self , void): #void is a var that I use
```

Comment: You also shouldn’t nest class definitions (even though you CAN do it, it usually makes your life harder).

Comment: @Samwise if I actually want to have each group of sprite for each Canvas object I instance then shouldn't I do that ?

Comment: No, the *instances* should be nested, but the *class definitions* should not.  The way this code is structured suggests that it's your first time working with classes in Python, and trying to do something graphical might not be a good tutorial.  I'd suggest looking up a more basic Python OOP tutorial to get yourself oriented on the basic concepts first.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

> the method function is declared with an explicit first argument representing the object, which is provided implicitly by the call.

> Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that relies upon such a convention.

So your first argument has a special meaning.

If we preserve your code (which we shouldn't), it should look like this to make it work:

```py
  def create_canvas(void):
     get_var = void.size
```

If we want to follow the conventions (which we should), it shoul look like this to make it work and look pythonic:

```py
  def create_canvas(self):
     get_var = self.size
```

Comment: I did what you just said but I have now an other Issue :
When I call this function it says that I'm giving 3 arguments instead of 2 

```
    corner_one = [0, 0]
    pos = [size[0] - 1, size[1] - 1]
    max_distance = (self.get_distance_between(corner_one, pos)
```

Comment: `self.get_distance_between` does not exist in your example. Update your example, providing the definition (at least the signature) of the method you define and the way you call it. But most probably you have something like this: `def method(self, one_param)` and then you call it like this `self.method(one_param, second_param)`. The second param doesn't exist in your signature, thus the error.